# Move text from one form to another

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a popup window with a combobox listing over 100 items.  I would like to make it so when the user selects the item and double clicks it will add the item to a textbox on another form (main form).  If more than one selection is made and added to the textbox, I'd like each to be separated by a comma in the same textbox.

Is this possible?

Main form is [f_Requests] and has a textbox called txtPractices
Popup form is [f_Practices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the DoubleClick event of the combobox, code something like:

```
Dim txtP As String
txtP = Nz(Forms!f_Requests.txtPractices,"")

If Len(txtP) > 0 Then
    Forms!f_Requests.txtPractices = txtP & " , " & nameofthecombobox
Else
    Forms!f_Requests.txtPractices = nameofthecombobox
End If
```

This can be improved checking first if the main form is opened.

Comment: This code is exactly what I was looking for, but this also add a coma in front of the first text (, cover, rock, etc.).  Is there an edit to ignore the common if its the first value?

Comment: When txtPractices is empty, I get "Invalid use of Null" and debugging highlights  the txtP = Forms!f_Requests.txtPractices portion of the code.  When txtPractices has a value, then other values are added.

Comment: What happens now is when the textbox is empty and I double click the combobox, the value gets added with a coma in front (, practice).  When I double click again to add another value, the first value is replaced, but without the coma (another practice).  Ideally I'd like to create a coma separated list in the textbox (practice, another practice, another practice, etc.) by double clicking the value in the combobox.  I feel like this is getting close and I appreciate all the help so far :-)